# How can it search inside the dictionary, if the dictionary is empty?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

I just started learning python and found this snippet. It's supposed to count how many times a word appears. I guess, for all of you this will seem very logical, but unfortunately for me, it doesn't make any sense.

```
str = "house is where you live, you don't leave the house."
dict = {}
list = str.split(" ") 
for word in list:  # Loop over the list
    if word in dict:  # How can I loop over the dictionary if it's empty?
        dict[word] = dict[word] + 1
    else:
        dict[word] = 1
```

So, my question here is, how can I loop over the dictionary? Shouldn't the dictionary be empty because I didn't pass anything inside? 
Maybe I am not smart enough, but I don't see the logic. Can anybody explain me how does it work? 
Many thanks

Comment: the dict is getting "filled" while the loop runs. it is only empty for the very first pass. Also, never use keywords for variable names. str, dict and list are being overwritten here.

Comment: You added a comment about loops with `if word in dict:`. The `if` statement is not a loop.

Comment: (And anyway, it's perfectly fine to loop over an empty collection, just like it's perfectly fine to multiply numbers by 0.)

Comment: @ParitoshSingh - `str`, `dict`, and `list` aren't keywords; they're just built-in functions. If they were keywords you'd get an error when trying to assign to them. That's why caution is required when considering names: it won't automatically catch that for you.

Comment: My bad, thanks. Wish i could edit my comment.

Comment: Thanks, everybody for your input.                                                                                
I have learnt more from you that focusing for over one hour on this piece of code by myself.

Comment: You are looping over a list, not a dictionary. You test if an element (word) exists in a dictionary. If not exists, you insert it with value 1. It exists, you are adding 1 to the value

Answer (score -2):

As somebody else pointed out, the terms `str`, `dict`, and `list` shouldn't be used for variable names, because these are actual Python commands that do special things in Python.  For example, `str(33)` turns the number 33 into the string "33".  Granted, Python is often smart enough to understand that you want to use these things as variable names, but to avoid confusion you really should use something else.  So here's the same code with different variable names, plus some `print` statements at the end of the loop:

```
mystring = "house is where you live, you don't leave the house."
mydict = {}
mylist = mystring.split(" ") 
for word in mylist:  # Loop over the list
    if word in mydict:  
        mydict[word] = mydict[word] + 1
    else:
        mydict[word] = 1
    print("\nmydict is now:")
    print(mydict)
```

If you run this, you'll get the following output:

```
mydict is now:
{'house': 1}

mydict is now:
{'house': 1, 'is': 1}

mydict is now:
{'house': 1, 'is': 1, 'where': 1}

mydict is now:
{'house': 1, 'is': 1, 'where': 1, 'you': 1}

mydict is now:
{'house': 1, 'is': 1, 'live,': 1, 'where': 1, 'you': 1}

mydict is now:
{'house': 1, 'is': 1, 'live,': 1, 'where': 1, 'you': 2}

mydict is now:
{"don't": 1, 'house': 1, 'is': 1, 'live,': 1, 'you': 2, 'where': 1}

mydict is now:
{"don't": 1, 'house': 1, 'is': 1, 'live,': 1, 'leave': 1, 'you': 2, 'where': 1}

mydict is now:
{"don't": 1, 'house': 1, 'is': 1, 'live,': 1, 'leave': 1, 'you': 2, 'where': 1, 'the': 1}

mydict is now:
{"don't": 1, 'house': 1, 'is': 1, 'live,': 1, 'house.': 1, 'leave': 1, 'you': 2, 'where': 1, 'the': 1}
```

So `mydict` is indeed updating with every word it finds.  This should also give you a better idea of how dictionaries work in Python.

To be clear, you're not "looping" over the dictionary.  The `for` command starts a loop; the `if word in mydict:` command isn't a loop, but just a comparison.  It looks at all of the keys in `mydict` and sees if there's one that matches the same string as `word`.

Also, note that since you only split your sentence on strings, your list of words includes for example both `"house"` and `"house."`.  Since these two don't exactly match, they're treated as two different words, which is why you see `'house': 1` and `'house.': 1` in your dictionary instead of `'house': 2`.

Comment: You're welcome!  Yeah, I don't know why I was down-voted either, let alone at least twice.